# guardar um tipo de dados em ficheiro em linguagem c

Tags: c, arquivo, hashcode

Tenho esta estrutura de dados:

```
typedef struct
{
    ListaCartao tabelaCartao[HASHSIZE];
    ListaArtigos tabelaArtigos[HASHSIZE];
    char localidade[MAXLOCALIZACAO];
}tCelulaSuperdume, *SuperDume;

SuperDume superMercadoLocal[CONJUNTOSUPERDUME];
char localSuperDume[MAXLOCALIZACAO];
int indiceLocalSuperDume = 0;
```

Dentro de `SuperDume` tenho duas tabelas de Hash. Depois tento guardar um `SuperDume` em ficheiro e não consigo:

```
void EscreveFicheiro(char nomeFich[])
{
    FILE* f;
    if (fopen_s(&f, nomeFich, "wb") == NULL)
        printf("Erro");

    else
    {
        SuperDume aux;
        for (i = 0; i < CONJUNTOSUPERDUME; i++)
        {
            aux = superMercadoLocal[indiceLocalSuperDume];          
            fwrite(&aux, sizeof(SuperDume) * CONJUNTOSUPERDUME,1,f);
        }
        fclose(f);

    }
}
```

O ficheiro abre, só que não consegue fazer o `fwrite`, retornando-me o seguinte erro:
[image: Erro]

Editado.
Tenho o seguinte código

```
void EscreveFicheiroCartoes(char nomeFich[])
{
    FILE* f;

    if (fopen_s(&f, nomeFich, "wb") == NULL)
        printf("Erro");

    ListaCartao aux;
    for (i = 0; i < HASHSIZE; i++)
    {
        aux = superMercadoLocal[indiceLocalSuperDume]->tabelaCartao[i];

        if (aux == NULL)
            continue;

        else
        {
            while (aux != NULL)
            {
                fwrite(&(aux), sizeof(ListaCartao), 1, f);
                aux = aux->proximo;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu não consigo achar a descrição de `fopen_s` no Standard de C; deves estar a usar um compilador não Standard :-)

A [descrição de `fopen_s` fornecida pela Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) e a maneira como usas o valor devolvido pela função não são coerentes ... por isso deduzo que também não seja essa a versão que estás a usar.

Vê no manual do teu compilador como funciona o teu `fopen_s`.

Ou usa a função do Standard que já tem dado provas ao longo de tantos anos

```
f = fopen(nomefich, "wb");
if (f == NULL) {
    perror(nomefich);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

Edit: encontrei o [`fopen_s` no Standard C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.2.1), no apendice K, como facultativo.

A descrição no Standard é coerente com a descrição da Microsoft.

> Returns
>
> The fopen_s function returns zero if it opened the file. If it did not open the file or if there was a runtime-constraint violation, fopen_s returns a nonzero value.

Ou seja, quando a função devolve `0` é porque "funcionou"

```
// NULL é automaticamente convertido para 0
if (fopen_s(&f, nomeFich, "wb") == NULL)
    /* fopen_s funcionou */
else
{
    /* fopen_s não funcionou */
}
```

Nota: a meu ver fica melhor usar `0` na comparação; não há vantagem em "meter `NULL` ao barulho"

Comment: obrigado , pensei que a forma segura do fopen funciona-se de igual forma que o fopen. Mas mesmo assim , não consigo escrever a estrutura em ficheiro, apenas me escreve um caracter : 'è' , nada mais

Answer (score 0):

`aux` é um ponteiro.

```
fwrite(&aux, sizeof(SuperDume) * CONJUNTOSUPERDUME,1,f);
//     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ tamanho dum ponteiro
//     \--> endereço dum ponteiro
```

Experimenta

```
if (fwrite(aux, sizeof *aux, CONJUNTOSUPERDUME, f) != CONJUNTOSUPERDUME) /* erro */;
//              \---------/  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ numero de elementos
//                tamanho de cada elemento
```

Mas não ponhas o `fwrite` dentro dum ciclo; ou então mete, mas com a esrita de apenas 1 elemento de cada vez.

Comment: ja tentei escrever o SuperDume (tipo de dados constituido por duas hash tables e uma "string" )

Mas não consegui nada, perguntei a um professor de outra linguagem de programação e ele disseme para utilizar o serialize. Andei a procura mas não entendi nada daquilo.


Entao decidi comerçar a guardar em ficheiro apenas as listas ligadas.